# How to make window.scrollTo(0,0) global?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `window.scrollTo(0,0)` on every component render for rendering the component to the top. But now I am trying to make it global as in other than calling `window.scrollTo(0,0)`in every component it should work from somewhere global.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

How I am using now:-

```
component A {
  render(){
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    return(<></>);
}
```

```
component B {
  render(){
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    return(<></>);
}
```

Similarly, I have to do for all the components that have the issue. 
I want to do it somewhere so that I don't have to call it in each and every component.

Comment: Please tell your problem more clearly

Comment: Erm... `window.scrollTo` *is* global

Comment: whatever declare on window object is global.

Answer (score 0):

you can use NPM [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/3f69f9e07b0a739419704cffc3b3563133281548/docs/GettingStarted.md) package to solve this. you should listen history like this:

```
history.listen(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0));
```

this will listen your routing history and set scroll position to 0,0 whenever its getting any change on history path.